# How to fill combobox column in DataGridView in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

My DataGridView contains three columns, column types are checkbox, textbox and combobox.

How can I load a row's combobox when the checkbox in the same row is checked?

Comment: http://www.rustemsoft.com/dgvcolumns.asp

Answer (score 8):

maybe this could help (example)

```
Dim dgvcc As DataGridViewComboBoxCell
dgvcc = DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(0)
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem1")
dgvcc.Items.Add("comboitem2")
```

[source](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/winforms-grids/10038-fill-datagridview-combobox-column.html)

Comment: How to get column name of selected combobox in datagridview

Comment: maybe...DataList1.SelectedValue.ToString

Comment: if i select "Comboitem1" from combobox,how to get a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn name for selected combo

Comment: check out this http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/31930-working-with-DataGridViewComboboxColumn.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can bind like this -

```
 Dim dtRange As DataTable = GetQueryTable("select range_name from table_name")
    Me.grid_column_name.ValueMember = "range_name"
    Me.grid_column_name.DisplayMember = "range_name"
    Me.grid_column_name.DataSource = dtRange
```

and this will bind table record to complete DataGridViewColumn of DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to filter the Datasource (in my case a dataset) when you edit another column that needs to filter the combobox column.  I find this super easy to code and efficient.

```
Private Sub DGV_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DGV.CellBeginEdit
Select Case e.Column.Name
    Case "TabID"
        Me.FormTabBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
        Me.FormTabBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("FormID =  {0}", DGV.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("FormID").Value)
    End Select
End Sub
```